# How to use new method in IOS 8 to find screenwidth when view size changes

Tags: ios

There is the following method in IOS 8 that is supposed to be used when a view's orientation changes:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize,
    withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

}
```

How can I use this to find the new width of the screen (I am making a keyboard app) when the screen rotates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the `size` passed as a parameter...